# Toolbar small to Medium by Text Lenght

Tags: android, android-toolbar, material-components-android

I'm  developing a toolbar that adheres to MD3 guidelines, but I'm unsure if this aligns with the intended use.
[image]

The toolbar will dynamically change its title based on server-received data. This text can be either short or lengthy. If the text fits comfortably within a single line, I'd like to use the small version (option 2 in the image). However, for extended text that overflows on one line, I prefer the medium version or large version(option 3 or option 4).I'm not aiming for the collapsing effect; I simply require two distinct size options.

Would this approach be considered appropriate? Is it feasible to achieve?

Also I'm considering to do this is in Compose as I seen I may get the results easier